# Python Setup on Debian, WSL - HDF5 package for tables (3.6.1)

Tags: python, linux, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Debian in conjunction with WSL. My goal is to get these python scripts to work in a linux environment.  I've recently tried to download a github project (using python files and Jupyter notebooks) with the following requirements saved in this text file.

https://github.com/codeworks-data/mvp-horse-racing-prediction/blob/master/requirements.txt

I keep getting this error code:

```
    Collecting tables==3.6.1
    Using cached tables-3.6.1.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
    Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [6 lines of output]
         * Using Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0]
         * USE_PKGCONFIG: False
         .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
            You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
            library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
            variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
          [end of output]

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

    × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
    ╰─> See above for output.

    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for details.
```

I can't seem to find any resolution on this, is this an environmental pathing issue ?

I've tried manually install the hdf5 package and defaulting to an older version of Python but I haven't had any success.